# Выбор ОСИ при загрузке

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu, dual-boot

Раньше у меня стоял `windows 8.1`, затем я поставил еще и `UBUNTU 14.04 LTS` при загрузке компьютера я мог выбирать какую ОС загрузить, но спустя время `windows` слетел и я его переустановил и с тех пор не могу запустить `ubuntu` т.к. сразу грузится винда.

На данном этапе ubuntu установлен на другом томе и он рабочий, но я не могу его загрузить. Как мне решить этот недуг? Я хочу, чтобы у меня была возможность при загрузке компьютера выбирать какую ОСь я хочу загрузить!

Comment: Либо играться с EasyBCD, либо загрузиться с любого linux live-cd и выполнить `update-grub`. Если вкратце, то в компьютере есть строгая последовательность загрузчиков разного уровня, и в данный момент загрузчик винды переписал загрузчик убунту (т.е. груб).

Comment: В целом же без жестких требований к производительности рекомендовал бы поднимать дополнительные ОС в виртуалках. С дуалбутом, к сожалению, вечный геморрой.